# Elasticsearch: results from multiple queries in one?

Tags: elasticsearch

have 4 different results in such kind of queries:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "desc",
      "query": "лес"
    }
  }
}
```

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "desc",
      "query": "лес*"
    }
  }
}
```

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "desc",
      "query": "*лес"
    }
  }
}
```

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "desc",
      "query": "*лес*"
    }
  }
}
```

The difference is the asterisk position.
Is it possible to get results from all four queries in one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't need to differentiate what query has determined a successful hit, then you can just use a boolean `should` query. Something like

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
      {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "desc",
          "query": "лес"
        }
      },
      {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "desc",
          "query": "лес*"
        }
      },
      ... 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Update with some recommendations on the queries**:

- I'm not sure what you need `*nec`, `nec*`, and `*nec*` for. If you are going to combine them, and you don't need to differentiate the hit match, isn't `*nec*` enough?
- I would recommend you switching from `match_query` to `match` (first query), `prefix` and `wildcard` (on the other queries, if you have non-analysed sub-fields available)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xw4CPeA1 constructed query. It's always same result (from query without asterisk). Even in reversed query order.

Comment: Didn't get the right result from `bool`. So i made 4 different requests and merged results. That's a heavy payload. But i don't know any other way at this time.

Comment: Do you get the expected results when you query using wildcards? I'm going to update my answer with some recommendations on the single queries

Comment: In my case `*nec*` and `*nec` are different in results. I thought that `*nec*` is a summ pattern for `*nec` and `nec*` but really it's not.

Comment: Solved. The default `"from" : 0, "size" : 10,` need to be extended cause i have more than 100 hits in `*nec*`.